# Zend framework PDF underline font

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I need to put underlined text into Pdf file with Zend Framework. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method `$page->setLineDashingPattern(array(3, 2, 3, 4), 1.6)`. I don't try this but maybe helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it works. Because here we need an underline rather than a dashed line.....
Correct me if I am wrong.....

Comment: Yes you are right. My opinion that Zend_Pdf is not very good. In our project we use dompdf - http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using.. the -2 is just arbitrary, but it looks fine.

Oh, and this is part of my method to center text but you could pull it out.

```
/**
 * Draw text aligned to the right
 * @param Zend_Pdf_Page $page page
 * @param string $text - text to draw
 * @param float $right - right position
 * @param float $top - top position
 * @param boolean $underline - whether or not to underline the text
 */
public function drawTextCentered(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $text, $top, $underline = false)
{        
    $textWidth = $this->getTextWidth($text, $page->getFont(), $page->getFontSize());
    $left = ($page->getWidth() - $textWidth) / 2;
    $page->drawText($text, $left, $top);
    if ($underline) {
        $page->drawLine($left, $top-2, $left+$textWidth, $top-2);
    }
}    

    /**
 * Return the width of generated string in points
 * @param string $text text
 * @param Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font font
 * @param integer $fontSize font size
 * 
 * @return float text width
 */
public function getTextWidth($text, Zend_Pdf_Resource_Font $font, $fontSize)
{
    $text = iconv('', 'UTF-16BE', $text);

    $chars = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) {

        $chars[] = (ord($text[$i++]) << 8) | ord($text[$i]);

    }

    $glyphs = $font->glyphNumbersForCharacters($chars);
    $widths = $font->widthsForGlyphs($glyphs);
    return (array_sum($widths) / $font->getUnitsPerEm()) * $fontSize;
}
```